# Copiar parte de uma string

Tags: delphi

Tenho as seguintes strings:

```
  Cliente em questão: protocolo20209092032932
  Cliente em questão 2: protocolo320930293232
  Cliente em questão 3: 20392039230902032032
```

Preciso fazer uma função para copiar tudo que estiver após o : (dois pontos) pra frente. é possível ? Lembrando que as strings antes do : não são do mesmo tamanho, por isso preciso deixar claro que tem que ser após : (dois pontos) pra frente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `Copy` combinada com a função `Pos`

```
TextoOriginal := 'Cliente em questão 3: 20392039230902032032';
valorTexto := Copy(TextoOriginal , Pos(':', TextoOriginal) + 1, Length(TextoOriginal));
```

Comment: boa na época que tentei fazer isso não sabia da função `pos` lol

Comment: @Caputo, deu erro na variável valorTexto, está dizendo que está faltando parâmetros.

Comment: tinha um parênteses errado @user7605. Já corrigi

Comment: Perfeito @Caputo, obrigado, e obrigado a todos que ajudaram!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como funciona em Delphi mas em PHP eu usaria a função "explode" que você define um delimitador e ele coloca tudo dentro de um array, por exemplo:

```
$cliente = "Cliente em questão: protocolo20209092032932";

$resultado = explode(':', $cliente);
```

Isso retornaria um array com dois valores:

[0] Cliente em questão
[1] protocolo20209092032932

E depois disso é só você fazer o que tem que fazer com sua variável $resultado[1]

Isso é só uma idéia de como eu faria em PHP, agora é só aplicá-lo ao Delphi.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, estou procurando se acho algo na internet parecido com o que você disse!

Comment: é possível por isso ai dentro de um while ? porque são várias linhas..

Comment: Se ele tiver mais de um ":" não vai fazer diferença, a única coisa que vai mudar será a posição do resultado no array, no exemplo que eu dei o resultado que você quer seria no $resultado[2]. Em PHP é possível colocar dentro um while sim já em Delphi não sei como funciona mas é bem provável que seja possível também.

Comment: em PHP como ficaria dentro de um while ? vou fazer em PHP mesmo...

Answer (score 0):

Fiz isso a mil anos atrás!

Na época criei uma função busca texto, para garantir que a string que estava procurando estava realmente dentro do texto.

```
Function BuscaTexto(Text,Busca : string) : string;
var n : integer;
begin
  for n := 1 to length(Text) do
    begin
       if Copy(Text,n,length(Busca)) = Busca then
          begin
             Result := 'ok';
             RetornoBuscaPos:=n;

          end;

    end;
end;
```

Repare que `RetornoBuscaPos` vai te dizer em qual posição a string foi encontrada, depois disso use a função `copy` para cortar onde deseja, faça algo parecido com isso:

```
  if BuscaTexto(MsgOriginal,':') = 'ok' then
    begin
    Resultado := Copy(MsgOriginal,RetornoBuscaPos,Length(MsgOriginal));
  end
```

Faça testes, faz tanto tempo que não uso Delphi estou enferrujado!

Comment: aonde eu vou setar nessa função que preciso buscar depois do ":" dois pontos ?

Comment: olha aqui `if BuscaTexto(MsgOriginal,':') = 'ok' then` se ele encontrar dois pontos ele vai retornar a posição e você usa o copy para cortar onde deseja

Answer (score -1):

olha q fácil em php, no meu exemplo as strings estariam um arquivo input.txt

arquivo input.txt

```
Cliente em questão: protocolo20209092032932
Cliente em questão 2:: protocolo320930293232
Cliente em questão 3::: 2039203923090203203
Cliente: em questão 3: 2039203923090203203
```

arquivo .php

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("input.txt", "r");
$contents = [];

while (!feof($handle)) {
  $str_array = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ":");      
  $str_array_count = count($str_array) - 1;      
  $last_index = $str_array[$str_array_count];

  $contents[] = $last_index;

}

fclose($handle);

print_r($contents);

?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  protocolo20209092032932
    [1] =>  protocolo320930293232
    [2] =>  2039203923090203203
    [3] =>  2039203923090203203
)
```

Comment: e se a string estiver duas vezes o ":" ? Como fazer ? agora que eu vi que tem duas vezes o :....eu preciso pegar o segundo ":".....tipo: Cliente: em questão 3: 2039203923090203203

Comment: editei o código pra adaptar pra mais de um ":", pode até ser três ou mais.